# Expose property for WPF user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

Here i've one user- control in WPF, which basically a shows folder tree in one pane and another pane(listview) shows files in that directory.

Now i exposed one property called fileextensionfilter which basically required to shows specific file only in listview. e.g. if fileextensionfilter= XML it shows only xml files.

Now in my main application i am using the above control thrice, but with differen fileextensionfilet e.g 1>xml another instance .pdf only and so on....

now i am getting the extension filter value from settings.default.xmlfilter,settings.default.PDFFilter so on......

here problem is when i load control properties of usercontrol is not initialized and i have something in constructor which makes uses of this properties and (at that time "null") so filter not working on first time. next once again its get refreshed the filter porperty will get applied and hence it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using your current property and use the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) Event to run the Code you are currently running in your constructor. Here is a small example:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <my:UserControl1 FileExtensionFilter="RTF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" x:Name="userControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <my:UserControl1 FileExtensionFilter="XML" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" x:Name="userControl2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <my:UserControl1 FileExtensionFilter="PDF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" x:Name="userControl3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**UserControl**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        string filter = "NULL";
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property" + filter + "Set during Constructor");
        }

        public string FileExtensionFilter
        {
            get { return filter; }
            set { filter = value; }
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property" + filter + "Set during Loaded");
        }

        private void UserControl_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property" + filter + "Set during Initialized");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

> PropertyNULLSet during Initialized
>   PropertyNULLSet during Constructor
>   PropertyNULLSet during Initialized
>   PropertyNULLSet during Constructor
>   PropertyNULLSet during Initialized
>   PropertyNULLSet during Constructor
>   PropertyRTFSet during Loaded
>   PropertyXMLSet during Loaded
>   PropertyPDFSet during Loaded

Comment: Nice try to explain me properly. Now let me open question in depth. Lets assume i have three tabs out of which i'm using the same control in two tabs, (kind of file explorer) now in one tab i want to show only pdf file and in another one i wanaa show only xml files so i tried to setup the filters accordingly.

Comment: @user1220402 The method I showed here should work, I have setup three of the same usercontrols and showed where the property has taken effect. Without seeing what your constructor contains I can not get anymore specific. As I said try moving the code in your constructor that uses the property into the loaded event.